# GetMapping in Springboot exclude html files in pathvariable

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, path-variables, get-mapping

I have a controller with the following GetMapping

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{path}") 
     public ResponseEntity searchAPI(@PathVariable("path") String API_NAME)
```

but I have to exclude /index.html from this GetMapping

I tried like this

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{path:^.*(?!index.html)}")
```

but this is not working
Do I need to write each API seperatly?
Please Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot (.) is a special character to match any sign, you need to escape it with a backslash:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{path:^(?!index\.html).*}")
```

Comment: Is there anyway to exclude all .html, .css and . js files